# modifying table size when sending email via python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, email

I have a pandas dataframe that I am sending to myself via email.
I am able to control the font size of the heading and body, however the dataframe itself is its default size which is a bit small for me.
How do I increase the font size of the table that is being sent?

Here is the html part of code I am using:

```
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <h1 style="color:red;font-size:25px;">This is My Header</h1>  
  <p style="width:50px;height:50px;">
  <body>
  {0}
  </body>
  </p>
</html>
""".format(df3.to_html())
consumptions = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(consumptions)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you have a Dataframe with a certain size you can add columns or rows if you need to make it bigger.

Comment: Does the generated HTML contain `style` setting the font size? if not, it will inherit the size from its parent element, so just put a `style` on `<body>`

Comment: @ivvija how do i specify the size of the fonts in the table after i put `<style>` ?